# Can't set custom font in Xcode 6 IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uilabel

I have added a custom font to my project, and it's registered everywhere properly (when I run the application I can see that the font is applied). However, when I select a `UILabel` in IB and try to set its font to this custom font, it does not work. The font shows up in the available fonts list however if I select it and apply the dialogue, the font property of the `UILabel` is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a bit of code to solve problem.

```
 [testable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont-Italic" size:18.0]];
```

Comment: My problem is around using the font in Interface Builder.